# C++ #define variable parameter function

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a CPU sensitive application and want to minimize function calls. I want to write something like:

```
#ifdef condition        
#define f(a,b) ff(a,b)   
#define f(a) ff(a)    
#endif
```

But the compiler sees f as defined multiple times. I wanted to use `__VAR_ARGS__` but in the example above `b` is of `enum` type. Is there a proper way to do it or I should just rename `f(a,b)`  to `f2(a,b)`?

To clarify the defines, if active, add calls to functions that process data for printing to file/stdout, otherwise they are replaced with empty lines, so in my opinion this method would improve code size and since the macro is single line keyword like `INFO(object->contents)` I think it's more readable. Also it would have been useful if I could have added something like `WARN("message")` and `WARN("value is",obj->printvalue())`.

I also think `inline` would do the trick (from the answer below).

Comment: I'm curious, how does it minimize function calls?

Comment: @StoryTeller I assume the OP meant there is no call to `f` which would just delegate to `ff`.

Comment: The question refers to code that has an #else which I found irrelevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very C-ish way of approaching this. Simply make it an overloaded `inline` function. Any optimiser worthy of the name will inline the call.

Answer (score 3):

My first guess is that you are optimizing in the wrong areas. Good compilers will optimize in this case. Obfuscating code will make it harder for the compiler to do so.

Comment: The define replaces allot of areas which in turn will reduce code size and most important make my source more readable. My define adds debug functions. I thought my question would be useful for other that might try to overload functions in define, that's why I didn't deleted it as soon as I found the answer. I don't see how your answer is useful to my question (on topic), as stupid as my question  would be.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from the c++ book:
Macro names cannot be overloaded:
     `#define PRINT(a ,b ) cout <<(a )<<(b )`
     `#define PRINT (a ,b ,c ) cout <<(a )<<(b )<<(c ) /* trouble?: redefines, does not overload */`